# How to assign IO memory and IRQs

Tags: memory, interrupt

I need to provide memory and IRQ resources to the Linux kernel in order to bring up the CAN controller. Have no idea how to get them.

Below is the structure I need to fill in. This structure I have taken for example, this is for the Run-Time Clock, but I need for CAN controller. Both are on the same board, and there are constants for RT Clock (and all other devices), but not for my CAN chip. When looking at the subject chip driver's code (sp_probe() function), I see it needs the same type resources.

```
struct resource tegra_rtc_resources[] = {
    [0] = {
        .start = ???,
        .end = ???,
        .flags = IORESOURCE_MEM,
    },
    [1] = {
       .start = ???,
        .end = ???,
        .flags = IORESOURCE_IRQ,
    },
};
```

All "platform" devices are added with their resources from the "board driver"  via the system function platform_add_devices(). The problem is that it initializes all the devices on my board (UART, RTC, I2C, NAND etc...) and NOT the CAN chip.
After device is added, this information can be passed to the device driver. The CAN chip driver itself is present in the kernel code.